# Why is my iOS build removed from the iTunes Connect Build section after processing?

Tags: ios, xcode, build, app-store-connect

I have uploaded three builds for version 2.3 but when I upload a new build in the iTunes Connect Build section it shows for some time like in the first image.

After some time, I refresh the page and it will remove the build like in the second image.

[image]
[image]

Now what should I do?

Comment: Maybe try using [**`Application Loader`**](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/apploader/ApplicationLoader_3.1.dmg) instead; it sometimes works in these situations.

Comment: I have already try both Application Loader and xcode

Comment: In that case I would contact the support, because your issue is definitely not normal.

Comment: I'm using xcode 7.3 and with apple watch programming.

Comment: Contact Apple, they should help you.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for your response.

Comment: Your privacy key has no description. Like "Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description" should have description.

Answer (score 0):

While you upload the build, you may see the upload process indicator may start from beginning some times. It may due to some sort failure in uploading.
There are some times you will get the success message, but the build upload will not be successful. In this you may try to upload the build again.

Comment: I have already try six time and upload six build but nothing display in iOS build section and when i try to same app version and build version than its generate error you have already upload this build in this version.

Comment: i am facing same issue.

Comment: @MssiOS have you received any mail from apple.